# How to get the value outside subscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

***my code***

```
this.service.getName().subscribe((success: any) => {
  if (success) {
    for (let i = 0; i < success[i].length; i++) {
      if (success[i].data.empid== data) {
        this.dataList.push(success[i].name);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Unable to access the `this.dataList` outside `subscribe`

Comment: Most likely relevant: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: You can't. Any statements that directly depend on `this.dataList` must be inside the subscription. In other words, subscribe where it's response is required. There are ways to cache a result from an observable though. Try googling it. At the end, the data must and _mostly_ will remain asynchronous and reactive.

Comment: Do you display this field in html ? Or do you try to read the value immediately after calling `this.service.getName()`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, need a value immediately after calling the service

Comment: You should simply put the code inside the subscribe, is there a problem with doing that? If so, you should expand on your question. The question as it looks now is identical to countless of other questions on this website

Answer (score 4):

You try to read `this.dataList` immediately after the call to `this.service.getName()` but you have an ordering problem. Consider the following piece of code :

```
this.service.getName().subscribe(() => console.log('A'));
console.log('B')
```

This will display `B A` because the call to `this.service.getName()` is asynchronous.

What happens is :

- Call `this.service.getName()`
- Call `console.log('B')`
- Browser get the response from `this.service.getName()` and executes `() => console.log('A')`

Because of that, you try to read `this.dataList` too soon, when it is still empty or `undefined`. You should read its value inside the callback :

```
this.service.getName().subscribe((success: any) => {
  if (success) {
    for (let i = 0; i < success[i].length; i++) {
      if (success[i].data.empid== data) {
        this.dataList.push(success[i].name);
      }
    }

    // Here, you can safely read this.dataList
    [...]
  }
});
```